# No matching member function for call to "erase"

Tags: c++, string, integer

I try to call erase() function to remove whitespaces in string for function that converts string to integer. The same code works in main() but inside function it doesn't.How can I fix it?

```
int convert(const string &line)
{

for (int i=0;i<line.length();i++)
{
    char wh=' ';
    if(line.find(wh))
        line.erase(find(line.begin(),line.end(),' '));

    //cout<<line[i];
}

if(line.length()==0)
    return 0;
int a=line[line.length()-1]-'0';
int b=convert(line.substr(0,line.length()-1))*10;
return a+b; 
}
```

Comment: `line` is declared as `const`; you can't modify on it.

Answer (score 0):

try to pass line by value instead of const reference. The const ref can't be changed

```
int convert(std::string line)
```

Comment: Thank you, it really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `const` from convert().
Anything declared with const can't be modified.